# VBA Excel- how to know the layout of data in a range

Tags: vba, excel

I am an Excel VBA newbie, though I have several years of programming experience.

I am trying to write a VBA function in excel where a user can input several cells in an application.inputbox by selecting individual cells, a cell range, or a combination of both.  Once input, I want to check the values for errors etc.

I can input the range without problem, but seem to need a way to inspect the range to determine its layout so I can find the values.  It seems the location of the values varies with how the user selected the cells.

Suppose the user selects 4 cells.  A1, A2, c2, f5 vs drag selecting A1:A2, and then clicking C2,f5.

in both cases Inputs.Count is 4.

In the first case Inputs(1)- inputs(4) do not return the selected values.
Here, in the first case, the values appear as single cells in 4 different Areas.

In the second case, Inputs(1)-Inputs(4) do return the selected values, yet these appear as three areas.  One area with two cells (two rows, one column), and two areas with one cell each.

I've two questions- 
1: Is there an easy way to determine where the data I want to inspect are (i.e., the layout of the range) without checking all the area/cell counts?

2: Where can I find an accessible read on using ranges.

Best,
Byron

Comment: it's really quite unclear what youre asking + i see asking for external resources which is off-topic here. All I can give you is `ActiveCell.Address` or `ActiveCell.Row` or `ActiveCell.Column` to get the **location**. Then write a function/sub that evaluates the location and provides you with results. Something that checks if all cells are in same column or row, etc.

Answer (score 2):

To compare a few methods after selecting A1,A2,B3,D4

```
Sub tester()

Dim c As Range, a As Range, x As Long, s

    Debug.Print Selection.Areas.Count

    Debug.Print "###By cell count"
    s = ""
    For x = 1 To Selection.Cells.Count
        s = s & " " & Selection.Cells(x).Address()
    Next x
    Debug.Print s

    Debug.Print "###For Each cell"
    s = ""
    For Each c In Selection.Cells
        s = s & " " & c.Address()
    Next c
    Debug.Print s

    Debug.Print "###Looping through areas"
    s = ""
    For Each a In Selection.Areas
        For x = 1 To a.Cells.Count
            s = s & " " & a.Cells(x).Address()
        Next x
    Next a
    Debug.Print s

End Sub
```

Output:

```
###By cell count
 $A$1 $A$2 $A$3 $A$4
###For Each cell
 $A$1 $A$2 $B$3 $D$4
###Looping through areas
 $A$1 $A$2 $B$3 $D$4
```

Only method #1 is unreliable - the others give consistent results however the range was originally selected.

Comment: perfect @Tim Williams, - many thanks.  I'd vote this up, but my rep is lacking.